# pylint(undefined-variable) on return render and object has no attribute errors

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

I'm working on a simple project with foreign keys on each model. The program worked well until I tried rendering the fetched data to a template.

When I tried getting a simple HttpResponse, it worked well, but rendering to a template gives me an error.

I get an error that states `Undefined variable 'required' pylint(undefined-variable)`

My code looks like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import master_courses, course_category, course_series


    def single_slug(requests, single_slug):
        categories = [c.course_slug for c in course_category.objects.all()]
        if single_slug in categories:
        matching_series = course_series.objects.filter(course_category__course_slug=single_slug)

            series_urls = {}
            for ms in matching_series.all():
                part_one = master_courses.objects.filter(course_series__course_series=ms.course_series).earliest("date_added") 

                series_urls[ms] = part_one

            return render(request, "main/category.html", {"the_series": series_urls})
```

The error points to the last line of the code, which is:

```
return render(request, "main/category.html", {"the_series": series_urls})
```

And it says **`undefined variable 'request' pylint(undefined-variable)`**

Other return statements work well except for that statement within the `for loop` as I've mentioned above.

Any suggestions on how I can solve this please?

Comment: Can you provide the code for `category.html`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is that your setting your first argument for single_slug as requests, as opposed to request, which is what your calling at the bottom after render.

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import master_courses, course_category, course_series


    def single_slug(request, single_slug):
        categories = [c.course_slug for c in course_category.objects.all()]
        if single_slug in categories:
        matching_series = course_series.objects.filter(course_category__course_slug=single_slug)

            series_urls = {}
            for ms in matching_series.all():
                part_one = master_courses.objects.filter(course_series__course_series=ms.course_series).earliest("date_added") 

                series_urls[ms] = part_one

            return render(request, "main/category.html", {"the_series": series_urls})
```

Try it like above.

Comment: Your suggestion worked for me. Thaks a lot. I just edited the question, could you please have a look at it and suggest?

Comment: If possible I think you should undo your edit and return this question to its original stage. Each thread should be about one question.. You've now made this thread into a thread about two different questions which will make it hard for people to follow. You should return this one to its original state and post a new thread with the new question.  Once you've done that I'll try to take a look for you. :)

Comment: I did as you've asked, and the new thread is linked to: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57177758/3288057